# Where do i place the <script>newBoard();</script>?

Tags: javascript, html

I've a problem, I need to put the newBoard(); in my JavaScript file. Where do I put it and how do I call it? And another question: can somebody write an object in this code?

Many thanks for your help!

This is the HTML file.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="memory.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="memory.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Koen's Heineken Memory Game:</h1>
        <div id="memory_board"></div>
        <script>newBoard();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the .js file.

```
var memory_content = ['A','A','B','B','C','C','D','D','E','E','F','F','G','G','H','H','I','I','J','J','K','K','L','L'];
var memory_values = [];
var memory_tile_ids = [];
var cards_turned = 0;

Array.prototype.memory_tile_shuffle = function(){
    var i = this.length, j, temp;
    while(--i > 0){
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
        temp = this[j];
        this[j] = this[i];
        this[i] = temp;
    }
}

function newBoard(){
    cards_turned = 0;
    var output = '';
    // De array wordt geschud.
    memory_content.memory_tile_shuffle();

    for(var i = 0; i < memory_content.length; i++){
        output += '<div id="tile_'+i+'" onclick="memoryFlipTile(this,\''+memory_content[i]+'\')"></div>';
    }

    document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = output;
}

function memoryFlipTile(tile,val){
    // Kijkt of de kaart nog niet is omgedraaid.
    if(tile.innerHTML == "" && memory_values.length < 2){
        // De achtergrond van de kaart.
        tile.style.background = 'white';
        tile.innerHTML = val;

        if(memory_values.length == 0){
            memory_values.push(val);
            memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
        } else if(memory_values.length == 1){
            memory_values.push(val);
            memory_tile_ids.push(tile.id);
            if(memory_values[0] == memory_values[1]){
                cards_turned += 2;

                memory_values = [];
                memory_tile_ids = [];

                if(cards_turned == memory_content.length){
                    alert("Goed gedaan! Ik zet een nieuw spel voor je klaar.");
                    document.getElementById('memory_board').innerHTML = "";
                    newBoard();
                }
            } else {
                function flip2Back(){

                    var tile_1 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[0]);
                    var tile_2 = document.getElementById(memory_tile_ids[1]);
                    tile_1.style.background = 'url(heineken.jpg) no-repeat';
                    tile_1.style.backgroundSize = '111px 111px';
                    tile_1.innerHTML = "";
                    tile_2.style.background = 'url(heineken.jpg) no-repeat';
                    tile_2.style.backgroundSize = '111px 111px';
                    tile_2.innerHTML = "";

                    memory_values = [];
                    memory_tile_ids = [];
                }
(flip2Back, 750);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if you want to call it after page is loaded `<script> window.onload = newBoard();</script>` you can place it anywhere in html but placing it below other `<script>` tags would be more readable

Comment: @Tilwin The JS is wrong. It has to be `window.onload = newBoard;` or `window.onload = function() { newBoard(); };`.

Comment: @usandfriends right.. i copy pasted the function name along with it from question...

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function on load:-

```
<body onload="newBoard()">
    <h1>Koen's Heineken Memory Game:</h1>
    <div id="memory_board"></div>
 </body>
```

Comment: It should make no difference as long as the function is called after the necessary DOM elements exist.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

Change your memory.js like this,

```
(function(){
      // add all your methods and declaration here

      newBoard();
})();
```

And change your html like this,

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="memory.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Koen's Heineken Memory Game:</h1>
    <div id="memory_board"></div>
    <script src="memory.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```